# Weird Value Oracle Insert Request

Tags: oracle, go

So, my code got oracle error this.

`ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`

But there is no long variable in the request.
After debugging, found out that one weird string value.

`, lor`

This causing of the problem, is there any way to parse that string back to normal?

Comment: It's pretty hard to dubug code that you cannot see.   Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.